# When creating histograms, what is wrong with data values falling on boundaries?

Tags: statistics

My textbook mentions this:

"To construct a histogram, first decide how many bars or intervals, also called classes, represent the data. Many
histograms consist of five to 15 bars or classes for clarity. The number of bars needs to be chosen. Choose a starting point
for the first interval to be less than the smallest data value. A convenient starting point is a lower value carried out to one
more decimal place than the value with the most decimal places. For example, if the value with the most decimal places is
6.1 and this is the smallest value, a convenient starting point is 6.05 (6.1 – 0.05 = 6.05). We say that 6.05 has more precision.
If the value with the most decimal places is 2.23 and the lowest value is 1.5, a convenient starting point is 1.495 (1.5 – 0.005
= 1.495). If the value with the most decimal places is 3.234 and the lowest value is 1.0, a convenient starting point is 0.9995
(1.0 – 0.0005 = 0.9995). If all the data happen to be integers and the smallest value is two, then a convenient starting point
is 1.5 (2 – 0.5 = 1.5). **Also, when the starting point and other boundaries are carried to one additional decimal place, no data
value will fall on a boundary**."

I don't get why it would be wrong if a data value falls on a boundary, can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intervals in a histogram is a range.

So if I made a histogram with bars $0-10$, $10-20$, $20-30$, etc.

And a data point said $10$, what would do? Would I put it in the first bar or the second bar?

We can go around this by making it $0-9.99..., 10-20.999...,$ etc

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is harmless that a data value falls on a boundary, provided that you only assign it to a single bin.

Avoiding the boundaries is a kind of voodoo protection.

---

Experimental data is given with a finite number of decimals, by rounding, so that the error on the values is uniform in a range of $\pm\frac12$ one unit in the last position. Shifting the decision limit by one half is useless.